# preserve json object used as dictionary with terser

Tags: javascript, typescript, uglifyjs, rollup, terser

I currently bundle my typescript code with rollup and want to use terser for minifying/uglifying. In my code I have a dictionary object and imported it into my typescript code.

```
const dict = { ironResource : "Iron" }
```

In my code I use it to translate identifiers to other languages or access configs by item identifiers (ironResource). Terser will mangle my keys and destroys the purpose of the object.

```
const B1 = { aB1 : "Iron" }
```

Terser settings:

```
terser({
        parse: {
        },
        compress: {
        },
        mangle: {

            properties: {

            }
        },
        format: {
        },
        ecma: 5,
        keep_classnames: false,
        keep_fnames: false,
        ie8: false,
        module: false,
        nameCache: null,
        safari10: false,
        toplevel: false,
    })
```

How to stop terser from doing this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would expect that you need to set mangle like this:

```
mangle: {
    properties: false
},
```

Or set the correct options in the [properties option object](https://github.com/terser/terser#mangle-properties-options) to keep those in particular. For example quote the property names and set `keep_quoted` to `true`.

Comment: set mangle.properties: false worked like a charm. thanks!